# How to perform Propensity Score Matching with panel data in Stata?

Tags: panel-data, stata, propensity-scores, matching

This is my first post on this forum so please forgive me if I overlooked something when posting this, but I very much hope you can help me out.

I am investigating the effect of hallucinogens use on anxiety level. My panel dataset contains data of 14,693 individuals of which 106 have used hallucs in one or more years. In total there are 13 annual waves, but not everyone has filled in every questionnaire so there's missing data.

I want to perform Propensity Score Matching (PSM) based on 5 demographic variables and 7 variables related to anxiety but not hallucs use (to decrease the variance of an estimated exposure effect without increasing bias, in accordance to Brookhart et al. (2016)). Some are continuous, some are categorial and some are binary.

In a course at university I learned the following code, but for cross-sectional data:

```
probit treatment [variables to match on]
```

However, when performing that like this...

```
probit treatment bmi_wave* fatigue* sleep_prob* cancer* geslacht leeftijd* oplcat* work* religious* dutch*
```

...I receive the error "convergence not achieved". I assume that means that no matches were made, and I also assume that is because it is now trying to match based on all 13 waves. Then a solution that comes to my mind is to perform this code like this for every wave separately:

```
probit treatment bmi_wave1 fatigue1 sleep_prob1 cancer1 geslacht leeftijd1 oplcat1 work1 religious1 dutch1
```

Then I do not get an error message, but I don't know how I should put all these 13 results back together into one effect. Any ideas on this?

Other codes the professor provided us with (y=net_income, x=college, all others are control variables):

```
teffects nnmatch (net_income iq_raven female SES yearofbirth) (college), atet

teffects psmatch (net_income) (college iq_raven female SES yearofbirth), nneighbor(5) atet

cem iq_raven(#10) female(#0) SES(#3) yearofbirth(#5), treatment(college) 
reg net_income college [iweight=cem_weights]
```

And furthermore I found a post on this blog mentioning the psmatch2 command. Again this works for separated waves but not when using *.

So the big question is: which command should I use?

I would be so grateful if you can help me out :)

Comment: PSM is likely the wrong analysis method for what you want to do. It sounds like you need a marginal structural model. This is an advanced method that likely requires the assistance of an expert. At its core, it involves fitting a propensity score model at each time point, converting the propensity scores into inverse probability weights, and multiplying the weights together across time points. See [Thoemmes & Ong (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1177/2167696815621645) for an introduction.

Comment: Dear Noah, 
Thanks a lot for your insightful comment! I dived into this method and I was wondering the following: it seems to me that this method is only useful when estimating the survival time after receiving a certain treatment. However, that is not really the case in my research, because individuals filled in their anxiety level every year (so not binary such as for example mortality). Do you agree with this or did I overlook something?

Comment: Additional question: is it useful for me to use inverse probability weighting? And then perform a regression taking into account these weights?

Comment: There is nothing about the method that is specifically designed for survival data; the examples in the paper I mentioned use a continuous outcome. So yes, you may have misunderstood what the method does if you thought it was only for survival/binary outcomes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is it useful"; to fit a MSM you have to use IPW.

Comment: Apologies, you are right. I think I thought it was only for survival time research because a lot of papers I found had that goal. 
Until now I have not found a complete explanation of how to perform MSM with a continuous outcome in Stata. https://remlapmot.github.io/cibookex-r/ip-weighting-and-marginal-structural-models-stata.html#program-12.7-1 is the closest I got, but without any explanation of what the commands are doing this will be too difficult for me. Therefore, I will stick to propensity score matching and deliver a less perfect research. 
Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions!